# Can this inverse Laplace transform be computed?

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I need to find the inverse Laplace transform of

$$F(s) =\dfrac{e^{\frac{K(1+K)}{1+K+s\Omega}+\frac{K(1+K)}{1+K+s\Omega\kappa}}}{(1+K+s\Omega)(1+K+s\Omega\kappa)}$$

where $K, \Omega, \kappa$ are constant.
I need to find the inverse Laplace transform of this expression,
i.e.,
find ${\cal L}^{-1}\left[F(s)\right]$.

Is there any publication of this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Looks like a step function and a convolution.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thanks for your kindly comment. Yes, it is.
Actually, it contains Bessel I function, exponential function, and step function before Laplace transform.
I want to calculate the convolution between two functions contains different parameters.